Where can I find data on typical size and temperature of a star given mass and age?
I am building a solar system and need to investigate my options. I need data to answer questions like "if a star was X solar masses and Y million years old, how large and hot would it be?" and "if a star is X metres wide, Y degrees kelvin and Z million years old, how massive would it be?"
I would really like a chart or table which combines data for star mass, age, diameter, and temperature. Where can I find this?

This is remarkably similar to another question asked recently, Luminosity and Radial changes in an Aging star, and the comments there might be relevant.

I'll point out that stellar models rely on creating a grid of initial factors (mass, metallicity, rotation), and then simulate stars' internal physics over time, which in turn affects observables like temperature and diameter. There isn't a two-way multi-dimensional grid of inputs like what you're looking for because not every age/diameter/temperature combination exists to extrapolate a possible mass from (and others might occur multiple times over the lifespans of different stars).

Take a look at the Hertzsprung-Russell Diagram. It will be very helpful so long as you understand the parameters.
